# c++ derived class needs to tweak base class via callback

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class

I would like to create a base class ==> derived class setup where the base class' constructor has a callback to run a (possibly complex) function to modify the base class' private member with information from the derived class. However, I'm running into a chicken and an egg problem because the base class constructor runs **before** the derived class' members are initialized. Here's the code to demonstrate the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class B
{
  public:
    typedef std::function<void(std::string &)> mod_func_t;

    B(const mod_func_t &m) : foo("base str")
    {   
      std::cout << "Base constructor\n";
      m(foo);
      std::cout << "base constructor finally has: " << foo << std::endl;
    }   

  private:
    std::string foo;
};

class D : public B
{
  public:
    D(const std::string &input) :
      B(std::bind(&D::my_f, this, std::placeholders::_1)),
      input_(input)
    {   
      std::cout << "Derived constructor\n";
    }   

  private:
    void my_f(std::string &s) 
    {   
      std::cout << "Derived class' modification function\n";
      s += input_; // <== Crashes here because input_ is not yet constructed
    }   

    const std::string input_;
};

int main()
{
  D d("my input");
  return 0;
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to let D calculate the adjusted `string` before calling the constructor of `B`.

```
class D : public B {
  D(std::string str)
   : B(my_f(str))
  {}

  std::string my_f(std::string str) { return str + "..."; }
};
```

A second approach is to let the body of constructor D do some work. Here `adjust_base` could also be `virtual`.

```
class D : public B {
  D(std::string str)
   : B(str)
  {
     adjust_base();
  }

  void adjust_base();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that CRTP could help you with this one..
There is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename Derived>
class B
{
  public:
 
    B() : foo("base str")
    {   
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->m(foo);
      std::cout << "Base constructor\n";
      std::cout << "base constructor finally has: " << foo << std::endl;
    }
    
    void m(std::string& str) { //... }   

  private:
    std::string foo;
    friend Derived;
};

class D : public B<D>
{
  public:
    D(std::string &input) :
      B(),
      input_(input)
    {   
      std::cout << "Derived constructor\n";
    }   
    void m(const std::string& str) { //... }

  private:
    void my_f(std::string &s) 
    {   
      std::cout << "Derived class' modification function\n";
      s += input_; // <== Crashes here because input_ is not yet constructed
    }   

    const std::string input_;
};

int main()
{
  D d("my input");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour: `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->m(foo);`. In `B()` there exists no `D` object yet.